# Wrong image path S3 Heroku Paperclip broken images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

Using s3 heroku and paperclip to store images.

I create an image through paperclip on my live app it saves to s3 but the images are broken on the view.

The html on the page for the broken image is:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/spreeas/users/profileimages/000/000/001/medium/ios.png?1401311581

the location of the same image on s3 is:

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/spreeas/users/profileimages/000/000/001/medium/ios.png

HTML update:

```
<a href="/profiles/1">
                <img alt="Missing" class="pull-left" height="25" width="25" <img="" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/spreea/users/profileimages/000/000/001/medium/ios.png?1401311581">
                &nbsp; yesterday            
              </a>
```

Has attached file update:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => "640x640>", :medium => "309x309>", :thumb => "100x100>", :convert_options => "-auto-orient" }
```

AWS config update:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Test:

I have created a new bucket and the image URL is as follows, it just seems to add '?1401317319' to the end of the image path: 
`http://s3.amazonaws.com/spreeab/sprees/images/000/000/004/large/wizkid.jpg?1401317319` any ideas?

Can anyone help here, not too sure how to get paperclip to generate the correct path so images are not broken? Thanks all, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your HTML that renders the image in the view?

Comment: HTML posted, thanks in advance

Comment: Neither of the links you posted work for me. It says the specified bucket does not exist. Are you sure "spreea" is the correct bucket name?

Comment: Can you share the `has_attached_file` specification from your `Profile` model class.

Comment: Hey mmichael my error, I have update thanks

Comment: has_attached_file updated

Comment: The error states: `The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.` I image this has something to do with the region of the bucket you created. Based on your URL above it's `eu-west-1`. I'm not entirely sure how to solve this but hopefully this will give you some more info. Also, any reason why you're not generating the image using the url attribute of the object that is saved on your app?

Comment: @Joshua I wanted to see the aws configuration. Where have you configured the aws bucket. Can you share it in the question?

Comment: Please could you explain further about generating the image using the url attribute of the object that is saved on my app?

Comment: @Kirti Thorat - aws config updated

Comment: I have created a new bucket and the image URL is as follows, it just seems to add '?1401317319' to the end of the image path: <img alt="Wizkid" class="center-block img-responsive" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/spreeab/sprees/images/000/000/004/large/wizkid.jpg?1401317319"> any ideas?

Comment: @Joshua In your view, to display the image you uploaded through Paperclip you'd want something like this: `<%= image_tag @profile.image.url(:medium) %>`. Passing in the size key (i.e. :medium) is optional - you can use any of the sizes you specified here: `has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :large => "640x640>", :medium => "309x309>", :thumb => "100x100>", :convert_options => "-auto-orient" }`.

Comment: My images were displaying fine until I changed the aws user and created a new bucket